# Are all node modules supposed to work out of the box with react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have tried using a couple of node modules with react native using npm install (specifically https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk/) and I continually get errors about dependencies not being resolved when I run the app.  Are node modules generally supposed to be supported by react native or only modules that are specifically written for it (such as this one https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-login).

Answer (score 0):

Many Node modules will not work with React Native. Some of the reasons are architectural and can be fixed (ex: currently React Native supports only asynchronous native methods while Node supports synchronous ones as well), while others are inherent to the fact that Node runs on V8 and React Native iOS runs on JSC.

As a heuristic, you should find success with Node modules that are utilities and depend only on JavaScript's core library (the APIs defined here: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html). This includes things like sorting algorithms, string formatting, etc.